# Changing appsettings.json on the fly and feed it in DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, appsettings

I am writing integration tests for my project and I have the following scenario.
I have a base class from where all the test classes inherit.
The constructor of my base class looks like this:

```
public KrampHubServiceIntegrationTestBase()
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
            .Build();

        _apiSettings = config.GetSection("ApiSettings").Get<ApiSettings>();

        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseConfiguration(config);

        var server = new TestServer(builder);
        _client = server.CreateClient();
    }
```

Now, when it calls **.UseStartup()** I suppose is the point where it says to go into my other project (Startup is part of the project I am testing) and use that Startup (which injects different interfaces and implementations where there are also the values of my appsettings.json). What I need to do is modify the appsettings.json, the **ApiSettings** session before that **Startup** starts working. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your test will use the appsettings from the test project, not the system under test so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Crowcoder I need to modify the appsettings.json for this reason. The appsettings.json that I will modify is the one coming from the integration test project that contains for example API urls. In different integration tests I test the different behavior of my project with different urls. So I need to find a way to modify the appsettings.json

Comment: I see. You might try using `.AddEnvironmentVariables`, then using `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` selectively in the tests to overwrite the value as needed. Since .Net Core configuration will use settings from any configured provider, your application can continue to use appsettings while your tests actually pull from environment variables.

Comment: couldn't find the right way but are you sure that **nvironment.SetEnvironmentVariable** allows me to set the value of a variable inside the appsettings.json ?

Comment: It doesn't set anything in the appsettings.json file, I'm saying that all configuration in .Net Core is consolidated, so no matter which provider a setting comes from (file, user secrets, environment, etc.) it will pull in. So as long as `AddEnvironmentVariables` comes after `.AddJsonProvider` it should work.

Comment: Okey.. then I need a few more details through code maybe. I am not an expert of these environment variables. If my code is supposed to read the settings from appsettings.json but then you say it doesn't matter where it come from, how does my code see the new value? could you please write some code for me on how to set the environment variable and make it being read by my project?

Comment: Actually, maybe that won't quite work. You would have to run the ConfigurationBuilder before each test.

Comment: Are you familiar with using the User Secrets feature of configuration? If so, it is the same concept. User Secrets injects settings into Configuration, but when you deploy to production the settings come from another provider. Think of configuration as one bucket, no matter how a setting was set, it will look the same to your code. Don't think of your settings as coming from appsettings.json, think of them coming from Configuration in general.